# Did the Pakistan intelligence director take part in prayers led by a Taliban leader?

Tags: pakistan, afghanistan

[According](https://www.republicworld.com/world-news/rest-of-the-world-news/pakistans-isi-chief-faiz-hameed-spotted-offering-prayers-with-talibans-mullah-baradar.html) to a  21st August 2021 article by (the not so reliable) [republicworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_TV),

> Pakistan's ISI Chief Faiz Hameed Spotted Offering Prayers With Taliban's Mullah Baradar [...]
>
> Recently, visuals of ISI chief have emerged with the Taliban.
>
> As per the pictures circulated on social media platforms, Pakistan's Director General of Inter-Services Intelligence, Faiz Hameed is seen with the Taliban leadership offering prayers led by Taliban Imam.
>
> The viral images also include Taliban co-founder Mullah Abdul Ghani Baradar and Sheikh Abdul Hakim, who is the Taliban's former shadow chief justice.

Did that event take place as described above?

(Note: that was before Faiz Hameed was moved to another position.)

Comment: Pakistani military has long been involved with the Taliban. Now the Taliban are the government of the country next door. Why are we surprised?

Comment: It's common for US presidents to pray with other world leaders e.g. at the [National Prayer Breakfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Prayer_Breakfast).  Idriss Déby the authoritarian leader of Chad was [reportedly invited](https://www.vox.com/2018/7/18/17586516/jeff-sharlet-maria-butrina-national-prayer-breakfast-the-family) one year, and there have also been complaints about Russian agents attending. Religion is supposed to bring people together.

Comment: @StuartF: yes, but those are rather public events, aren't they (3,000 guests)? AFAICT no Pakistani or Afghani media has covered this (at least in English), although maybe they thought it was unremarkable.

Comment: I found coverage of a Sep 5 official visit, which is probably not the same. https://tolonews.com/afghanistan-174522 (No joint prayer is mentioned.)

Comment: @Fizz Are you Pakistani?